# Firing OnCreatingModelDataSource event in ASP.NET Web Forms applications

Tags: asp.net, webforms, model-binding

All ASP.NET data bound controls have an additional event in ASP.NET 4.5, CreatingModelDataSource. It provides a great way to create our own implementation of ModelDataSource and bind to a control like GridView.

I created a sample ModelDataSource and hooked it up with a GridView in the CreatingModelDataSource event as follows:

```
protected void gvStudent_CreatingModelDataSource(object sender, CreatingModelDataSourceEventArgs e)
{
   e.ModelDataSource = new MyModelDataSource((GridView)sender);
}
```

Following is the sample ModeldataSource implementation that I wrote:

```
public class MyModelDataSource : ModelDataSource
{
    MyDataSourceView view;
    public MyModelDataSource(Control control)
            : base(control)
    {
    }

    public override ModelDataSourceView View
    {
        get
        {
            if (view == null)
            {
                view = new MyDataSourceView(this);
            }
            return view;
        }
    }
}
```

And following is MyModelDataSourceView:

```
public class MyDataSourceView : ModelDataSourceView
{
    private MyModelDataSource _owner;
    private StudentRepository repository;
    public MyDataSourceView(MyModelDataSource owner)
        : base(owner)
    {
        _owner = owner;
        repository = new StudentRepository();
    }

    protected override IEnumerable ExecuteSelect(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments)
    {
        return repository.GetAll();
    }
}
```

But the ExecuteSelect method doesn't get called automatically. It gets called when I set a SelectMethod to the GridView. As the result of ExecuteSelect method is finally bound to the GridView, specifying the SelectMethod doesn't make any sense here. Also, the event is not fired when gridView.DataBind() is called. Is there any way to kick off the things and make this event called automatically?

Answer (score 0):

CreatingModelDataSource() was put in for the Model data source which is used in Model Binding.  When you use model binding you need to specify the Select() method for model binding to work with GridVIew

Comment: Ideally, what should the select method in this case contain? I tried with a Select method returning null and it worked well. I also observed that the select method is never executed as the control didn't hit the breakpoint on this method